# javascript: window.open as synch for Chrome or Firefox

Tags: javascript, synchronous, window.open

I am using aspx with framework 1.1 (client specification) and I need some solution to simulate the same behavior of **window.ShowModalDialog** of IE5.

At the moment I am deteting if I am using Chrome or not. After that in the popup I select a date of an calendar and I can send to the parent without problems.

As you know showmodaldialog is deprecated in Chrome and the pruposal is **window.open**. The problem of this it is window.open is asynch and I need the synch behaviour.

I DONT WANT JQUERY SOLUTION. I don't have this "modern" technology because I am maintaining an old version which will die soon.

Only Javascript solution will be nice for me.

Do you have a solution for a synch window.open?

Thx

Comment: Put the HTML in a <div> instead and show that like a modal. Completely sync, and doesn't require the user to tell their browser to allow popups.

Comment: Did you check the [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog#see_also) there is a link to a polyfill on github.

Comment: F YI, `window.open` is not an asynchronous call

Comment: @phuzi when you put a console.log after window.open, I see in console the messagte before clicking in the date of calendar in the modal window. Then the behaviour is not synch. showModalDialog is synch and doesn't continue the execution after you close the child opened

Comment: From the documentation on the linked page above - "The open() method of the Window interface loads a specified resource into a new or existing browsing context (that is, tab, window, or <iframe>) under a specified name." This will cause the tab/window/iframe to be opened with the url specified. This tab/page/iframe then exists in a completely different context, this asynchronous behaviour is not we traditionally mean by async JavaScript which started with callback and Promises but now actually uses the `async` and `await` keywords.